# Bootstrap Columns arent in a row

Tags: jquery, slick.js, bootstrap-5

The result of this code is that the columns are not in a row. I am using Slick in this section. Can someone tell me why?

These Slide are the things that I want to slide.

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div data-aos="fade-right" class="first-slider pt-5">
      <!--Slide 1-->
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-12"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-12 order-md-last order-first desktop-section">
          <h1 class="heading3 mb-3 text-white">Test 1</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Slide 2-->
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-12"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-12 order-md-last order-first desktop-section">
          <h1 class="heading3 mb-3 text-white">Test 2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolo</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Slide 3-->
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-12"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-12 order-md-last order-first desktop-section">
          <h1 class="heading3 mb-3 text-white">Test 3</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Here the JS for slick

```js
//slick
$('.first-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    appendDots: $('.slick-slider-dots'),
    prevArrow: $('.slick-prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.slick-next'),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/arpitdalal/pen/eYRmjoR) which shows how to implement the `slick-carousel` with `jQuery` and `Bootstrap-5`.

**NOTE: link jQuery and jQuery-migrate before the slick.js file**

**NOTE: link both slick.css and slick-theme.css**

The CDNs used to create the above Codepen.

[bootstrap](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css)

[slick.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css)

[slick-theme.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css)

[jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js)

[jQuery-migrate](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.3.2/jquery-migrate.min.js)

[slick.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js)

See the [official docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started) on getting started from slick carousel.

Comment: I have used all the NOTES and the CDNs but I want the picture on the left and the text on the right in one row.

Comment: I have updated the codepen with that change, you just need to replace your classes `row align-items-center` with `d-flex`. I suggest using flexbox for this and not use bootstrap's grid system for various reasons. You can remove or keep the `col-md-5 col-12` stuff to make it responsive.